# Не удаётся открыть файл для чтения

Tags: c++, linux, c, файлы

Код следующий:

```
if ((pfp = fopen("etc/enet.cfg", "r")) == NULL)
{   
    printf("Unable to open enet.cfg\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Открыть файл не удаётся, т.е. в данном случае печатается сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Добавьте в свое сообщение `%m` (или вызывайте `perror()`) и Вы увидите, что за ошибка.

    if (...) {
      perror("fopen enet.cfg");
      // или
      printf("Unable to open enet.cfg: %m\n");
    }

В Вашем случае, думаю, тривиально нет такого файла.

Comment: А права на чтения этого файла у вас есть?

Comment: Права есть.

Comment: А что у Вас за linux? У меня ни на RedHat, ни в xubuntu такого файла в /etc просто нет. 

Что в нем должно быть?

Comment: Fedora. Думаю, какой именно файл и где находится не имеет значения. Проблема в том, что не удаётся прочитать этот файл.

Comment: Другие, например /etc/passwd читаются?

Comment: нет. Аналогичная ситуация.

Comment: задам глупый вопрос: а выше этого ифа есть данная строчка?:

    File *pfp;

а библиотека < stdio.h > подрублена?

если и это непомогло то прописать путь от диска "C:\...etc\enet.cfg"...
и вообще мне кажется слеш не в ту сторону!!!!

Comment: @Дарьялла. А что значит "не открывается", причина-то какая? Другими словами, что печатает perror?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, если все это не было сделано, программа просто бы не скомпилировалась

>прописать путь от диска "C:...etc\enet.cfg"...

Это просто нечто. Вы в юниксе, сэр, здесь вам не виндовс.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, вы забыли слэш: `"/etc/enet.cfg"`.

Comment: со слешем та же ситуация

Comment: `ls -la /etc/enet.cfg`

Comment: И что `%m` говорит?

Comment: Не найден файл или директория.

Comment: Значит такого просто нет.

А что у Вас за linux? У меня ни на RedHat, ни в xubuntu такого файла в /etc тоже нет.

Что в нем должно быть?

Comment: Есть этот файл)

Comment: ls -l его показывает?

Comment: полные права